# Multiple instances web service with load balancing - save requests data

Tags: load, amazon-ec2, cloud, load-balancing, instances

I will try to describe my question clearly.
Suppose I ran a Java REST web service on Amazon EC2.
A HTTP request gets to one of my services with a string "testString". I save it in the memory on some general class, let's say I add it to a list ('stringsList') of strings.

**My question is: If I have multiple instances of my web service, will this string be available on each one of these instances ?**
If a user will produce a HTTP request that calls "stringsList.getString('testString')",
it will get the string for sure ? Or it can miss it, because it is available, but on a
different instance of my web service ?

I want to be able to ran my web service as a scalable one with load balancing, and multiple
instances, but still to be able to save some specific HTTP requests information (maybe this
is exactly why the REST should be stateless, hence my design is wrong if I wish to do this
? ).
The web service I aim for is something like this:

[Scalable web service (from Heroku)](https://phpfog.com/images/architecture-diagram.png?1300842614)

I will try to give details, although I'm not so sure:

1. If I ran the web service through SSH to my EC2 instance, and there is only one like
   this, it will not be a problem, right ?
2. If I do the same, but for many instances, and through Amazon Elastic load balancing ?
3. If the answer to 2 is that there can be a miss, but I still want to achieve this, what is the alternative way ?
4. Maybe it's not a good idea to do this on Amazon EC2, but on a different service ? If so, which one ?

   - To put it in a database is not what I want, I want to save it only for a few hours in the memory for what I need.

Thanks,
Liran

Answer (score 1):

Memcache seems like the natural choice for this problem. However it is not only available on Google App Engine. You can also run you own Memcache server on EC2 if you so desire.

Answer (score 0):

There's no "shared memory" concept on Amazon and, no, that string will not be available on all instances. The is the simple database, but you say you don't want to use a DB.

It is possible to always direct a user to the same instance they were first directed to using cookies on the load balancer, but it doesn't sound like this solves your problem, I guessing that string isn't just for the user that sets it.

Google App Engine might be better suited. It supports [Memcache](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/) across the servlet instances you use and all the servlet instances can access the same memcache.